# snowflake case statement - Return 1 if value exists in column, else return 0

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to simply return a 1 (for true) and a 0 (for false) if a value exists in a column.

The table looks like below

```
Col A 
1/1/2020
1/2/2020
1/3/2020
<null>
```

and the target output would be like below:

```
Col A     Col B
1/1/2020  1
1/2/2020  1
1/3/2020  1
<null>    0
```

Is it possible to do a case statement to create Col_B such that I return a 1 for if a value exists in col A and 0 if a value does not exists in Col_A ?

Something like this:

```
SELECT * ,
CASE WHEN d.COL_A exists then 1 
ELSE 0 END AS Col_B

FROM Data D
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you just want to compare to `NULL`?

```
select (case when columnA is not null then 1 else 0 end)
from data d;
```

Answer (score 0):

Throwing out other alternatives supported by Snowflake

Using `decode`

```
select decode(colA, null, 0, 1) as colB
```

---

Using `iff`

```
select iff(colA is null, 0, 1) as colB
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answers work perfectly well ... however I think this is a perfect time to use [NVL2](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/nvl2.html) especially if you like cleaner looking code or less typing :-)

```
SELECT NVL2(COL_A,1,0) FROM CTE
```

[image]

Copy|Paste|Run:

```
WITH CTE as 
  ( select '2020-01-01'::DATE COL_A
    union select '2020-02-01'::DATE COL_A
    union select '2020-03-01'::DATE COL_A
    union select null  COL_A) 

 SELECT COL_A, NVL2(COL_A,1,0) COL_B FROM CTE
```